# Implement Equality method for Generic type classes?

Tags: c#, generics

I have to implement Equals method for below generic class.

```
public class SomeIdentifier<T>
        {
            public T Id { get; set; }
            public String Name { get; set; }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                var other = obj as SomeIdentifier<T>;
                if (other == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return Id == other.Id && Name == other.Name;
            }
        }
```

But I am not allowed to compare  `Id == other.Id` as both are of type T.

I am getting below error message ***Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T' ***

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you know that T is a reference type you can declare it on class definition:

```
public class SomeIdentifier<T> where T : class
```

Comment: This assumes that the type should be a reference type (there's no basis for that assumption, the OP may well expect to handle value types) and also this will always do a reference comparison, and we don't necessarily know that that's the correct way to compare the types in this context.

Comment: Quite right... An EqualityComparer could be used instead

Comment: you're right, this is another possibility.